# Iterate over rows in Python, count and stop when certain value is reached

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration

I have a dataset which contains a lot of items for which I track the status each week (so an item can occur multiple times in the dataset). I would like to build logic which counts the number of consecutive weeks an item has had a given status. Per item I would like to see how long it was status "z" and preferably in which week the item was status "z" for the last time. I only want the counter to start from the first week the item became status "z". Once it runs into a week where this item was no longer status "z" I want the counter to stop and insert the value it has at the original row. For all weeks I only want to take historical weeks into account. (Week 2 should not take week 3 into account).

Furthermore, I would like to include the most recent week it had status z. Also, for items which don't have status z in the current week I would like to see when the last week was when status z was applicable.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'WeekNr': [202301,202302,202303,202304,202305,202301,202302,202303,202304,202305], 'Status': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'A', 'A', 'Z', 'Z'], 'Item': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y','y']})

First, I sort my dataframe to make sure we iterate in a chronological order:
df.sort_values('WeekNr', ascending = False)

check = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for index2,row2 in df.iterrows():
        if row["Item"] == row2["Item"]:
            if row2["Status"] == "z":
                check += 1
        elif row["Item"] == row2["Item"]:
            if row2["Status"] != "z":
                row["Check"] = check
        else:
            continue
    Check = 0    


Preferred output would be:
202301    A    x    0    -
202302    A    x    0    -
202303    A    x    0    -
202304    Z    x    1    202304
202305    Z    x    2    202304
202301    Z    y    1    202301
202302    A    y    0    202301
202303    A    y    0    202301
202304    Z    y    1    202304
202305    Z    y    2    202304

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong/suggest some improvements?

Thanks!
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
# sort by Item/WeekNr
df = df.sort_values(by=['Item', 'WeekNr'])

# identify Z
m = df['Status'].eq('Z')

# group by successsive Status
group = group = df['Status'].ne(df.groupby('Item')['Status'].shift()).cumsum()

# set up grouper
g = df.groupby(group)

# add counter
df['counter'] = g.cumcount().add(1).where(m, 0)

# Get first WeekNr, or previous one for Z
df['Check'] = (g['WeekNr'].transform('first')
                 .where(m).groupby(df['Item']).ffill()
              )
```

Output:

```
   WeekNr Status Item  counter     Check
0  202301      A    x        0       NaN
1  202302      A    x        0       NaN
2  202303      A    x        0       NaN
3  202304      Z    x        1  202304.0
4  202305      Z    x        2  202304.0
5  202301      Z    y        1  202301.0
6  202302      A    y        0  202301.0
7  202303      A    y        0  202301.0
8  202304      Z    y        1  202304.0
9  202305      Z    y        2  202304.0
```

Comment: This works absolutely perfect for the WeekNr! Thanks! However, i'm still struggling how to add the counter of how long it was status "z" at that specific point. Do you have any suggestions to tackle that issue?